# Where does Artemis stand in the Star Trek timeline?

Tags: star-trek, timeline, star-trek-eu

The multiplayer co-op game and Star Trek Bridge Simualator, [Artemis](http://www.artemis.eochu.com/), presents the players with the ability to roleplay their own scenarios with their own personal crew and ship.  As such, the game itself is not likely to be considered "canon" - more like an alternate possibility that is separate from, and doesn't conflict with, any other events in the Star Trek universe.

Yet, with the timeline of the Star Trek universe going on for so long, and the level of technology varying widely throughout, the game has to fit somewhere chronologically, even vaguely.  Anyone have a good idea where?

The presence of Space Stations akin to Deep Space 9 (not similar in appearance, just in prominent placement across the map; they are all even appropriately titled DS-#) suggest at least beyond Enterprise and probably beyond Original Series as well.  There are also probably a number of hints to be gained from the choice of enemies that you fight, but I am unfortunately not familiar enough with the lore to make meaningful deductions from that myself.

Comment: Deep Space Nine was originally the Cardassian station [Terok Nor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Terok_Nor) - if the Federation is building more in the same design, it's a waaay alternate universe...

Comment: @Izkata Sorry, I might have misworded that...  They don't visually look like DS9 at all.  They appear like "generic" space stations, really.  The similarities I mean was simply that they do, in fact exist prominently, and I know they wasn't the case if you go far back enough in time to series like Enterprise.

Comment: Although we’ve established this game isn’t actually Star Trek, [there were “Deep Space” stations during the Original Series](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-7), so their presence wouldn’t have ruled out a Kirk-era setting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My name is Brian, and I'm the community manager for Artemis.

I'd like to clarify:

Artemis was started about three years ago and the Author, Thom Robertson, is not affiliated with any Star Trek clubs or fandom.

While Artemis clearly has its roots in classic Star Trek, it was quickly adopted by a small (but growing!) fanbase, who suggested changes, changes which took Artemis into it's own Canon.

Artemis was never meant to be "Star Trek", just a means for folks to grab some older computer equipment, and play spaceship crew in their living room!

Artemis is the brainchild and creation of one man, Thom, not a Star Trek fan club.  :)

I hope this clarifies where Artemis came from!

Thanks!

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for the answer right from the source, Brian!  That means a lot!  I was informed that Artemis was developed by a section of a Star Trek Club, but it seems I am mistaken.  Obviously, this post is the -definitive- answer, no doubt possible.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, take a look at the Manual from [here](http://www.artemis.eochu.com/?page_id=160), page 40:

> At the time Earth’s richest nations had sent a handful of unmanned probes to other stars, but the entire human race had never banded together to accomplish anything. Then the threat of interstellar war brought out the finest in us. Soon scientific breakthroughs came every day, and engineers were designing starships, terraforming planets, and building outposts in deep space. Even as we spread to the stars, our politicians devised schemes to gain allies. **Thus the United Space Faring Planets was born.** This united mankind in a single, benevolent government that was open to other races.

Additionally, the USFP ships only have the vaguest relation to Federation ships from Star Trek; they have bulges that look like nacelles, and an area shaped similarly to the saucer section, but a lot of them (like the Transports and Scounts, page 43 of the manual) don't even look like Federation ships to me.

This isn't set in the Star Trek universe at all; it's a vague look-alike.  Probably due to copyright restrictions, since they *are* selling it.

The manual does give a timeline on pages 40-41, though.  In this universe, First Contact was made about a century after First Contact on Earth in Star Trek.

Comment: Interesting... I apologize for completely overlooking that PDF manual.  Either way, it surprises me to find out that, despite being so CLEARLY a "Star Trek game" (created by members of an International Star Trek club), it doesn't bear the name or its universe anywhere in it.